# Return Boolean if Rails Object Contains Specific Value in a Specific Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to write a rails/activerecord query that returns true if a rails object contains a specific value.  I have a join table called 'Events' between 'Users' and 'Bicycles' and the Events table has a column called 'event_type'.  I'm trying to find out if a specific Bicycle's last created event contains the event_type 'stolen'.  I want to return only true or false, not the rails object itself.

I have been able to return the last event object with no problem using:

`Bicycle.find(:id).events.last`

And I can return true or false if there is *any* event registered to that bicycle that contains event_type 'stolen' by using:

`Bicycle.find(:id).events.where("event_type='stolen'").count.positive?`

How can I return true only if the last event on the object contains event_type 'stolen'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to laugh at how obvious the answer is...

```
Bicycle.find(id).events.last.event_type == "stolen"
```

One minor edge case to account for, however, is: What if there are **no** events for that `bicycle`?

In that case, `Bicycle.find(id).events` will return an empty collection, so `Bicycle.find(id).events.last == nil`. This means the above code would raise an exception: `NoMethodError: Undefined method event_type for nil:NilClass`.

However, a simple workaround would be to use the [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537):

```
Bicycle.find(id).events.last&.event_type == "stolen"
```

Comment: Another minor point: You say you want the "**last created** event", but - assuming you have not done something unusual like change the `default_scope` - your `.last` code will actually be returning the `Event` with the highest `id`. Which will *probably* be the same thing, but not necessarily. In order to guarantee you're fetching the last `created_at` event, you'd need to `order(:created_at)`. When in doubt, check the SQL that's generated by viewing the rails log!